# How to make minor upgrade in Windows Installer always overwrite?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I tried `REINSTALLMODE=amus` option but it didn't work showing error message `Another version of this product is already installed...`.

If I give `INSTALLMODE=vomus` option it works well. But, some files are not overwritten, not updated. Maybe it seems to be a file version related problem. Is there really no way to force WI to overwrite its files except doing major upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the MSDN topic [REINSTALLMODE property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The "v" is needed by the minor upgrade, the "o" tells it to only overwrite older files and the "a" tells it to reinstall all files regardless of hash or version.

So REINSTALLMODE=vamus should be what you need.  However, if the files in the installer were properly versioned this shouldn't be a problem in the first place.